# Python os.environ from a different system

Tags: python, api, operating-system

i would like to store my API token as environment variable. which works top locally as follows:

```
url = "https://myURL.org/"
token = os.environ['NETBOXTOKEN']

nb = pynetbox.api(url=url, token=token)
prefix = nb.ipam.prefixes.get(9)
new_prefix = prefix.available_prefixes.create({"prefix_length": 48})
print(new_prefix)
```

However, I want to run the os.environ call on a foreign system, preferably via ssh.
I don't want to use subprocess which is:

```
token = subprocess.check_output('ssh user@ip echo $NETBOXTOKEN', shell=True)
print(token)
```

I can't find an explanation how to query an env with os.environ on a foreign system.

Comment: There’s no explanation because that’s not how `os.environ` works. What exactly are you trying to do with this, and why do you want to avoid subprocess?

Comment: ah okay. I want to store the token on the server so that the script works for everyone who has access to the server.